# Find similar names using Couchbase server 3.0 and port 8092

Tags: couchbase, nosql

I want to find the similar location names using couchbase server. i created an index as follows

```
function (doc, meta) {
  emit(doc.loc_name, doc);
}
```

this is how i query data

```
http://IP Address:8092/dev-locations/_design/dev_test_view/_view/searchByLocationName?full_set=true&inclusive_end=true&stale=false&connection_timeout=60000&key=%22Joh%22
```

But this will return only if the exact match found. What i am looking for is when i send the key `joh`, it should return `johenaskirchen` and `johenasberg` (same as our LIKE in MySQL)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Note : I already tried N1QL and i am looking for ways to implement this without N1QL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `key` parameter is an exact match. What you want is a combination of `startKey` and `endKey`:

```
?startkey=%22joh%22&endkey=%22joh\uefff%22
```

The `\uefff` is a trick, this unicode character can be seen as "the biggest character" so it ensures that a key like `johzzzzzz` will still be considered under the upper bound of `joh\uefff` (`endkey` is inclusive).

Comment: I made a mistake in the special char, prefer using `\uefff`