# How to do a conversion of a RegEx sql query from: SQL Query to Couchbase NoSQL?

Tags: javascript, sql, regex, couchbase

I am new to Couchbase and I'm quite confused with the regular expression of Javascript. I do not know how to write a query in Javascript for Couchbase NoSQL which contains regular expression.

I have a SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NAME LIKE ‘abc%’;
```

I want to search all records with starts with 'abc', 'ABC', etc (case doesn't matter). Example matches are: "abc ...", "ABC...", "ABC anything".

Comment: Why don't you post what you've tried?

Comment: By the way, that is not a regular expression. It's a search with wildcards.

Comment: Please check [Matching Fields That Start With a String in Couch](http://blog.mattwoodward.com/2011/05/string-matching-in-couchdb-views.html). I think that is almost all you need.

Answer (score 0):

**In Couchbase 3 and below**

You'd have to have a `view` that emits the `NAME`. From here, use the SDKs or the [REST API to query the view](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Views/views-querying.html).

Note that you can only do "starts with" with views, by using `startkey` and `endkey` with the `\u0000` suffix for endkeys (see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268624/find-similar-names-using-couchbase-server-3-0-and-port-8092/31273863#31273863)).

Also by default views are case sensitive, you have to normalize your emitted data, so in your case instead of emitting the `name` field in your JSON (`doc.name`) as is, emit `doc.name.toLowerCase()`. Then query the view with:

```
startkey="abc"&endkey="abc\u0000"
```

**In Couchbase 4 (in beta): N1QL!**

With Couchbase 4 BETA comes [`N1QL`](http://docs.couchbase.com/4.0/n1ql/index.html), SQL for Documents!
You can do `LIKE` queries with it. In fact this would be pretty close to the SQL version since N1QL is a superset of SQL (`SQL++`):

```
SELECT * FROM theBucketContainingUsers WHERE type = "user" AND LOWER(name) LIKE "abc%"
```

I included the `type` constraint because generally in Couchbase you store different kinds of documents in a single Bucket and one way of separating them is to include some kind of type field in the doc itself.